# Finding the position of a specific value in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

Is it possible to easily find the position of a specific value in a list? For example, if the list is `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...,{xn,yn}}` I would like to know the position of `y = 123456.78`. I would prefer to not use `If`.

Comment: Look into  `Position[]`.

Comment: oh, thanks. I didn't know this option...

Comment: There is a [subtlety](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750623/using-position-correctly) for using `Position`, which is good to know. On an unrelated matter: why don't you accept those answers to your previous questions which you like or prefer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `Position` function. Which returns a list of the positions of the pattern you are searching for.

```
k = RandomInteger[10, {10, 2}]
(* ->{{2, 10}, {9, 3}, {9, 10}, {8, 1}, {2, 0}, {10, 10}, {10, 0}, {10,6}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}} *)

Position[k, 3]
```

returns

```
{{2, 2}, {9, 1}, {10, 1}}
```

Which is a list of the indices of the three occurrences of 3 in the list, `k`.

Comment: @Harald you are welcome :)

Comment: is there way to find position on the 1st level, but with criterion pointing on 2nd level 2nd position?
Eg. To return position of 1st level list that contains `3` on the 2nd position in it, then return `2` as a result.

Answer (score 11):

`Position[]` is the function you want:

```
la = RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, {8, 2}]
{{-4, -4}, {1, -8}, {3, 0}, {-2, -3}, {-3, -1}, {4, 9}, {2, 4}, {0, -2}}

Position[la, 0]
{{3, 2}, {8, 1}}

(* check results *)
la[[##]] & @@@ %
{0, 0}
```